# Why use an ArrayList to receive RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS

Tags: android, speech-recognition

Just as the title says, it seems that RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS only ever returns one string so why would we need an arraylist?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

read this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognizerIntent.html#EXTRA_RESULTS) and this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognizerIntent.html#EXTRA_CONFIDENCE_SCORES) for your answer

`public static final String EXTRA_RESULTS`

> *Added in API level 3*
>
> An ArrayList of the recognition results when performing ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH. Generally this list should be ordered in descending order of speech recognizer confidence. (See EXTRA_CONFIDENCE_SCORES). Returned in the results; not to be specified in the recognition request. Only present when RESULT_OK is returned in an activity result. In a PendingIntent, the lack of this extra indicates failure.

*Constant Value: "android.speech.extra.RESULTS"*

`public static final String EXTRA_CONFIDENCE_SCORES`

> *Added in API level 14*
>
> A float array of confidence scores of the recognition results when performing ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH. The array should be the same size as the ArrayList returned in EXTRA_RESULTS, and should contain values ranging from 0.0 to 1.0, or -1 to represent an unavailable confidence score.
>
> Confidence values close to 1.0 indicate high confidence (the speech recognizer is confident that the recognition result is correct), while values close to 0.0 indicate low confidence.
>
> Returned in the results; not to be specified in the recognition request. This extra is optional and might not be provided. Only present when RESULT_OK is returned in an activity result.

*Constant Value: "android.speech.extra.CONFIDENCE_SCORES"*

Comment: "this list should be ordered in descending order of speech recognizer confidence". So EXTRA_RESULTS actually returns an array of values ordered by confidence? So the string value at index 0 is the value that speech recogniser deems most likely to be accurate?